# How can ion-side-menus open implicitly with both sides visible?

Tags: ionic-framework

I would use ion-side-menus as of ionic-starter-sidemenu but implicitly init with both sides open.
I used expose-aside-when = "large" but in this case the menu-toggle button does not work, does not hide the left side when I press. Is there another solution?
Thankyou